# unknown column but it does exist?

Tags: sql

Here is my update query:

```
UPDATE products
SET products_status = 0
WHERE (`products`.`products_id` = `products_to_categories`.`products_id` 
       and `products_to_categories`.`categories_id` = 114)
```

The error I am getting is:

> 1054 - Unknown column 'products_to_categories.products_id' in 'where clause'

But when I go to the table products_to_categories there is a column products_id.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You aren't selecting anything from the products_to_categories table. You would need to add a subquery to select which products_to_categories.products_id you want to match on.

Comment: But isn't that in my Where clause?

Comment: All you're telling the UPDATE statement to do is to change the products table. The products_to_categories table is outside of the scope of this query and that's why you're getting the error.

Comment: So I need to add a select statement to the WHERE statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you need is probably this one:

```
UPDATE products
SET products_status = 0
WHERE products_id IN 
(SELECT products_id 
 FROM products_to_categories
 WHERE categories_id = 114)
```

Answer (score 0):

got it:

```
UPDATE products
SET products_status = 0
WHERE (SELECT products_id FROM products_to_categories
WHERE(
`products`.`products_id` = `products_to_categories`.`products_id` and `products_to_categories`.`categories_id` = 114))
```

Comment: That is still not valid sql query syntax.  See my suggested query.

Comment: yes I can see why yours is prettier. and looks more usable. mine did however work anyways. Thanks for your help.